# Write Hawk script to monitor and notify the BW stub and component running status

Tags: tibco

I'm new to hawk script and i have no idea about the syntax for this script.
I need to write a hawk script which monitors the Stub and sends the status in regular intervals.
Any help please!!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Hawk Rule (using the Hawk UI) that calls the getComponentInstanceStatus method on the TIBCORuntimeAgent (COM.TIBCO.admin.TRA) micro agent.